# unable to properly load 16bit tiff with imread in opencv

Tags: image, opencv, 16-bit

I am currently trying to use opencv to process a 16 bit tiff image. However the image matrix returned by ***imread*** seem to be filled with '255' values. I have tried using  the flag **CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH** and -1 but it all does not seem to work. When i check with the debugger, the datatype for the matrix storing the image is set to unsigned char which seems to be the source of the issue. Its this issue with the Mat class where it is unable to store image which are higher then 8-bit?

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you ask the quetsion on answers.opencv.org ? I guess you may have faster feedback on such specific implementation issues.

Comment: Yup I did over there too.

Comment: I found this, not sure if it helps you though: http://answers.opencv.org/question/13115/cannot-view-16-bit-grey-level-images/ . Did you manage to write then read 16 bit images?